# Could not resolve peer dependency while installing a package

Tags: angular, npm, dependencies, angular-cli, txtextcontrol

I made an Angular 9 library with a few packages on it, but whenever I run an npm install one of the external packages throws the error below 'Could not resolve peer dependency @angular/common@"^8.2.6"'.
I've tried installing with '--legacy-peer-deps' but that didn't do the trick since the package does not work anymore after installing it like that. Another thing to note is that in my client, also Angular 9, the install and the package worked fine. How does one overcome this error?
[image: npm Error]

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~9.1.13",
"@angular/common": "~9.1.13",
"@angular/compiler": "~9.1.13",
"@angular/core": "~9.1.13",
"@angular/forms": "~9.1.13",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.13",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.13",
"@angular/router": "~9.1.13",
"@mdi/font": "^5.1.45",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
"@schematics/angular": "^9.1.8",
"@txtextcontrol/tx-ng-document-editor": "^29.0.0",
"ecarelib": "0.0.402",
"rxjs": "~6.5.4",
"tslib": "^1.13.0",
"zone.js": "~0.10.2"},


"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.15",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.901.15",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.15",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.13",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "ng-packagr": "^9.0.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the package does not work" in "the package does not work anymore after installing it like that"? What are you seeing that indicates the package is not working, and what makes you think it's tied to the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag?

Comment: I'm able to install errorless with the flag but when I try to build the library for production I get errors related to the package that's missing the peer dep (txtextcontrol)

Comment: What's the error? Are you sure it's related to the install and not something else?

Answer (score 0):

run `ng update`.
then run `npm audit --fix`.
then run `npm i`.
tell me if it worked.

Comment: run npm update
the problem is your version of the packages are not compatible with eachother.